# Is there such a thing as OCR for detecting form fields?

Tags: ocr

Trying to automate a system here, either through off-the-shelf or roll-your-own solutions: how to take a PDF form (e.g. membership, taxes, etc.) and detect fields? Preferably along withe the label(s), type, length, etc..

All the OCR I've seen is directed at reading text, but not other forms of content.

Note: I'm NOT trying to capture responses, but to capture blank fields on an empty form.

Comment: Did you code the system / have you looked at the HMTL? Do the form fields have [meaningful Ids](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_name.asp)? If so, parse the HTML

Answer (score 1):

What about [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) or 1 of the many wrappers for your favourite programming language? You can recognise both [text (OCR)](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/) and [rectangles](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/).